# Increment firebase value from javascript, subject to constraint

Tags: javascript, firebase, firebase-realtime-database

I have a value in firebase I need to increment, it's subject to race conditions so I'd prefer to do this all in one.

```js
    node: {
      clicks: 3
    }
```

I need to set `clicks = clicks + 1` so long as `clicks < 20`. Is there a single call I can make from the Web API to do this?

Comment: Can you use a Firebase validation rule? Something like `".validate": "newData.val() < 20"`

Answer (score 23, accepted):

See the [reference documentation for a transaction](https://firebase.google.com/docs/reference/js/firebase.database.Reference#transaction):

```
var ref = firebase.database().ref('node/clicks');
ref.transaction(function(currentClicks) {
  // If node/clicks has never been set, currentRank will be `null`.
  return (currentClicks || 0) + 1;
});
```

The above will simply increment the value atomically, without having he option of users overwriting each other's results.

Next up, make sure that the values can never be > 20:

```
var ref = firebase.database().ref('node/clicks');
ref.transaction(function(currentClicks) {
  // If node/clicks has never been set, currentRank will be `null`.
  var newValue = (currentClicks || 0) + 1;
  if (newValue > 20) {
    return; // abort the transaction
  }
  return newValue;
});
```

For good measure you'll also want to set up your security rules to only allow clicks up to 20. Security rules are enforced on the Firebase Database server, so this ensures that even malicious users cannot bypass your rules. Based on the examples in the [Firebase documentation on validating data](https://firebase.google.com/docs/database/security/securing-data#validating_data):

```
{
  "rules": {
    "node": {
      "clicks": {
        ".validate": "newData.isNumber() && 
                      newData.val() >= 0 && 
                      newData.val() <= 20"
      }
    }
  }
}
```

Answer (score 10):

There's a new method `ServerValue.increment()`in firebase JavaScript SDK v7.14.0

It's better for performance and cheaper since no round trip is required.

See [here](https://firebase.google.com/support/release-notes/js)

> Added ServerValue.increment() to support atomic field value increments without transactions.

API Docs [here](https://firebase.google.com/docs/reference/js/firebase.database.ServerValue)

Usage example:

```
firebase.database()
    .ref('node')
    .child('clicks')
    .set(firebase.database.ServerValue.increment(1))
```

Or you can decrement, just put `-1` as function arg like so:

```
firebase.database()
    .ref('node')
    .child('clicks')
    .set(firebase.database.ServerValue.increment(-1))
```

Comment: Amazing... I prefer this over a transaction. Good to know!

Comment: What's the alternative for Web version 9?